# illegal use of undefined variable, class, or 'void' literal

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-plugins

I am getting below exception whenever trying to call JavaScript Function using below code:

> Assertion failure message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``vars.put("FinalData", decode64(PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiI . . . '' : illegal use of undefined variable, class, or 'void' literal

Below is the BSFPostProcess:

```
function decode64(input) {
     var output = "";
     var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
     var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
     var i = 0;

     // remove all characters that are not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, or =
     var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
     if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
              "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
              "Expect errors in decoding.");
     }
     input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

     do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

        if (enc3 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }
        if (enc4 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

     } while (i < input.length);
     return output;
}
```

I am trying to call this under BSF Assertion Sampler using below code.

```
vars.put("FinalData", decode64(${Data}));
```

OR

```
vars.put("FinalData", decode64(vars.get("Data")));
```

Data is variable and stores value:

> PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9InllcyI/Pgo8UmVxdWVzdFBhcnRzUmVzcG9uc2UgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly9zZXJ2aWNlcy5teWNjY3BvcnRhbC5jb20vQWx0ZXJuYXRlUGFydFNvdXJjaW5nL0FsdGVybmF0ZVBhcnRTb3VyY2luZyI+CiAgICA8UGFydFJlcXVlc3RJZGVudGlmaWVyPjQwNTM4MTU8L1BhcnRSZXF1ZXN0SWRlbnRpZmllcj4KPC9SZXF1ZXN0UGFydHNSZXNwb25zZT4=

`FinalData` is predefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not how preprocessor works, you have 2 options:

- create a class that contains decode64 method , package in a jar and put it in lib folder
- use commons-codec http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html as it is already in jmeter dependencies

Anyway you would remove the function declaration in preprocessor

Comment: I did tried that but getting below exception, its something with Jar i guess because i tried to put simple function which return String that works fine but same class has decode function it doesn't work. I looked in to Jar and i can see the jars and classpath pointing to same.. - `import JmeterAutomation.*; Javadecode dc=new Javadecode(); print(dc.testme()); S . . . '' : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name

Comment: Just try my second option or give more detail about the class you put in Jar

Comment: Second option worked for me, but i still want learn how to get JAR working in my JMETER project. In my code i have performed same thing as you mentioned in Second option. Is there any way i can attach my JAR here?

Comment: package JmeterAutomation;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

public class Javadecode{
 public String decode(String s) {
     return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(s));
 }
 public String encode(String s) {
     return Base64.encodeBase64String(StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(s));
 }
 public String ReplaceMe(String input){
  return input.replace("RequestPartsResponse", "GetPartRequestStatusRequest");
//  return "Tested";
  
 }
}

Comment: Done, Thanks for your help...I figure that out, my JAR does have the External Jar but the above code somehow unable to access those. I just manually copied those jar in lib and it worked.